# Sony Camera SDK version 2.3 not available on website

Tags: sdk, sony, sony-camera-api

I went to the Sony website to get the latest version of the SDK.
https://developer.sony.com/downloads/all/sony-camera-remote-api-beta-sdk/
On that page is info about the SDK but no way to download.  I have tried this from Chrome, Edge and InternetExplorer.  Is the link broken or am I at the wrong link?
Chris

Comment: Asking for downloads is EXPLICITLY off-topic

Comment: So how else can I get this info?  There is no other help on the Sony website except StackOverflow.  And why is it EXPLICITLY off-topic?  Did you decide that?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. While having the SDK may eventually lead to programming questions, how to get the SDK has NOTHING to do with programming, and is off-topic.

Comment: I have downloaded previous versions from the web site and someone from Sony monitors this group for questions.  I was hoping they could help.  I have asked and answered programming questions previously. If I can get the new SDK maybe I can contribute useful info.  Unless you are familiar with the Sony SDK I am not sure you can comment.

Answer (score 1):

The main download page is broken for me also, but this link does work: https://developer.sony.com/downloads/camera-file/sony-camera-remote-api-beta-sdk/

Comment: Please don't answer to questions asking for external links, that's not what SO is made for.

Comment: I did see the exchange in the comments above. But if the official Sony links are broken, where else to turn to?

Comment: I don't know, the question itself is just off-topic for SO, so is the answer. It's nice trying to help anyway :-)

Comment: I have looked thru the help for SO and do not see that this subject is off-topic.  I genuinely was looking for help on a question on software development.  I tried other possible sources and found none.  When I post or answer a question I am trying to help not chastise people for trying to be helpful.  People not interested in helping but troll looking for people to take away reputation points from seems more against the spirit of the site than innocently asking for help.  Since my original comment the Sony web site has been fixed so now the SDK is available for download.

Comment: I knew that someone from Sony monitors this forum and hoped they would see the issue.  Maybe they did and that is how it got fixed!